# Pandas Reading File Header Incorrectly

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, python-import

This is my first post, so I apologize if I leave anything out.

The situation/problem: I'm trying to import a .csv file into a SQL table. This file has all kinds of weird stuff going on with it. The file uses double quotes to mark the start and end of a row, which isn't ideal. The header is like this (I use spaces between some of the letters as there are spaces between these header names like "Date Range" and I have to keep the data and things like that as discreet as possible):

`" A , B B , C C C , D D D D , E E E E , F F F "`

The rows themselves are formatted like this (Sorry, I couldn't figure out how to put this in one code snippet):

`" REQ.123 , 2021-01-01 to 2021-01-31, G, 55, $1234.56 , $789.12 "`

Firstly, the quotations are throwing me off, and I'm not quite sure if the Pandas Read_CSV interprets these as row indicators or not. There's also a total row at the bottom that I am removing. I tried the following when doing my read_csv function:

`df = pd.read_csv(file_path, engine = 'python', skip_blank_lines = True, delim_whitespace = True, warn_bad_lines = True, skipfooter = 1).replace('"', '', regex = True)`

The compiler said I needed to specify the python engine since I'm removing the footer. Also, I'm trying to remove the quotations from the file since I don't think it'll run correctly without this. This code runs fine, but it's doing something weird where I think it's duplicating headers or something because it looks like this when I print the dataframe:

`A , B B , .1C C C , .2D D D D , .3E E E E, .4F F F`

The values under the headers are another problem because of the '$' in float numbers, but I'll have to make another post for that after figuring out what's going on with these headers. When I ran a "df.shape," it's showing (2,58), which I assume it's only picking up 2 headers. I also want to rename the headers to more database friendly names like:

`A , BB, CCC, DDDD, EEEE, FFF`

But when I do the

`df.rename({'B B':'BB'}, axis = 1, inplace = True)`

It's not changing the name, and I'm not sure why. I'm sure if I can figure out the first issue, I can figure out this one. Thank you for you time in advance. I can try to make a mock-up of the csv file, if that helps. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I seemed to have fixed this myself with the following read_csv excerpt: ```df = pd.read_csv(file_path, skip_blank_lines = True, delimiter = ' , ', warn_bad_lines = True, skipfooter = 1).replace('"', '', regex = True)``` It didn't get rid of the double quotes in my headers, so I just had to rename them with the quotes included in the first and last column header name.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.